# How to get version number when using Chef to deploy application

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, fabric

I am using Jenkins to build the application in the testing server, after that, jenkins executes a fabric script in which a chef script will be executed in the production server.

In the chef script, first i have to get the jar to be deployed from github, and i want to get the version generated during the testing phase, so the question is how can i get this version number.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the application should be held in attributes. Then you are able to overwrite it very easy on every chef run. Just create a json file with the needed application version and feed it chef client or solo on next run:

```
chef-client --json-attributes path/to/file.json
```

This override attributes that are set from other locations, such as from within a cookbook or by a role.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:

1. use `chef-client -j ...`. This is ok when you target a single server or a group of servers. It can get complicated for multiple/complex deployments as you will have to set and distribute different json attributes per app.
2. Write the artifact version to a data bag item e.g.:
   `knife data bag from file applications myapp.json`. Your `myapp` cookbook is coded to look for the required app version info in the `applications/myapp` data bag item.
   I created a Jenkins plugin that does this: https://github.com/zhelyan/jenkins-chef-artifact-release
3. Code your cookbooks to grab the artifact from the Jenkins server itself e.g from: `https://jenkins.mycompany.com:8080/job/myapp/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/myapp.war`, have a look here for details: https://github.com/woohgit/jenkins-chef-traceability-example

Implementing option 2 or 3 will also give you a deployment dashboard page showing what got deployed where.